# HTML relative URL starts at C drive instead of current location

Tags: html, url, path

I have my website in the folder C:/Users/username/Desktop/pathname_website. Within the pathname_website folder I have aboutus.htm and index.htm. In aboutus.htm I have the link `<a href="/index.htm">Home page</a>`. I want it to go to the index.htm file, obviously, but it leads to C:/index.htm, which in addition to being the wrong location, doesn't even exist.

Why is it trying to start at the C drive and not the current location? This is Windows 10. I tested on multiple browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `<a href="./index.htm">Home Page</a>`

This path is relative to your codebase

Answer (score 0):

Change to `<a href="./index.htm">Home page</a>`